# VIM Insert PHPdoc automatically

Tags: vim, phpdoc

Is there a way to insert PHPDoc in VIM using a command or key combination?

For example, I have a class:

```
class MyClass
{

  public function __construct() { }
  public function __destruct() { }

  /* command here to insert PHP doc */
  public function abc() { }

}
```

I would like to insert something like:

```
/**
* method() 
*
* description
*
* @access   
* @author    
* @param    type    $varname    description
* @return   type    description
* @copyright
* @version
*/
```

And then I can full out the rest manually. Thank you

Comment: phpdoc.vim [here](http://markus.fischer.name/vim/phpdoc/), PDV [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1355), http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatically_generate_PHPdoc_comments; you [could try google](http://tinyurl.com/65l8bkw) next time

Comment: @sehe I did try google but I found very complicated solution. I wish I would be as smart as you

Comment: no problem; I'm not trying to put you down. However, if you _did use_ google, it is nicer to say so in the post. Tell us what you did find, and what part was giving you trouble - that way, people can _really_ help instead of giving the obvious answers only

Comment: @sehe oh yeah, good idea thanks, still new at this but learning;)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This can be done pretty effectively with the lightweight [phpDocumentor plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1355).

**Edit** [Here's a modified version](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2980) with more recent development.

**Edit** [Here's version 2 of the phpDocumentor plugin](https://github.com/tobyS/pdv). It is more recent than the above two links.

Install the plugin into your `$VIMFILES/plugin` directory and add this to your .vimrc:

```
" PHP documenter script bound to Control-P
autocmd FileType php inoremap <C-p> <ESC>:call PhpDocSingle()<CR>i
autocmd FileType php nnoremap <C-p> :call PhpDocSingle()<CR>
autocmd FileType php vnoremap <C-p> :call PhpDocRange()<CR>
```

The above binds phpDocumentor to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> in insert, normal, and visual modes.  Place your cursor on a class, function, or variable definition, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>, and the plugin will attempt to form a doc block based on the definition.

#### Example function doc block:

```
/**
 * testDocBlock 
 * 
 * @param mixed $param1 
 * @param mixed $param2 
 * @static
 * @access public
 * @return boolean
 */
public static function testDocBlock($param1, $param2) {
  // Pressed Ctl-p while cursor was on the function definition line above...
}
```

#### Example class doc block

Copyright, version, author, etc are included by default in a class doc block. You can modify the plugin to include your own default values for these:

```
/**
 * TestClass  
 * 
 * @package 
 * @version $id$
 * @copyright 
 * @author Michael <me@exmaple.com> 
 * @license 
 */
class TestClass {

}
```

#### Full abstract class example:

```
<?php
/**
 * TestClass 
 * 
 * @abstract
 * @package 
 * @version $id$
 * @copyright 
 * @author Michael <email@example.com>
 * @license 
 */
abstract class TestClass {
  /**
   * publicProp  
   * 
   * @var string
   * @access public
   */
  public $publicProp;
  /**
   * privateProp  
   * 
   * @var string
   * @access private
   */
  private $privateProp;

  /**
   * testDocBlock  
   * 
   * @param string $param1 
   * @param string $param2 
   * @static
   * @access public
   * @return boolean
   */
  public static function testDocBlock($param1, $param2) {
    // code here...
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Tha mapping was `<C-P>` but the shortcut was <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> which lead to [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12881340/546861). I fixed the mapping.

Comment: There is another version with php7 support: https://github.com/Rican7/php-doc-modded

Answer (score 4):

Assume you place your template at ~/templates/phpdoc.php.
With the below abbreviation, if you type `,p`, you will
read the contents of your phpdoc.php into the current file,
( at or below the current line - one of those ).

```
map ,p :r ~/templates/phpdoc.php<cr>
```

Then just add the line to your .vimrc file, replacing the
file-path and `,p` to your liking.

Comment: This is kind of similar to what you want too, but with MIT license with some extra bells and whistles, showing how you could potentially reduce some of the manual work with templates:  http://vimeo.com/30391489 or http://vimeo.com/30441772

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for PHP specifically but you have a couple of options. You can use [abbreviations](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_abbreviations) (maybe not good for the specific example) or you can look for a plugin. I can suggest https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate ( I use it and it works fine).