# Binding PHP documenter script to <C-P> in Vim

Tags: plugins, vim, phpdoc

As suggested in an answer here:

[VIM Insert PHPdoc automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7603446/vim-insert-phpdoc-automatically)

I was trying to bind <kbd>Ctl</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> to the PHP documenter script in order to generate comments.

I used these lines at the end of my .vimrc file:

```
" PHP documenter script bound to Control-P
autocmd FileType php inoremap <C-P> <ESC>:call PhpDocSingle()<CR>i
autocmd FileType php nnoremap <C-P> :call PhpDocSingle()<CR>
autocmd FileType php vnoremap <C-P> :call PhpDocRange()<CR>
```

But when I press <kbd>Ctl</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>, the cursor goes to the line before and the comments are not generated.

However if I manually execute the command:

```
:call PhpDocSingle()
```

It works fine, so I know the php-doc.vim plugin is correctly installed and the problem is about the keyboard shortcut.

I've searched in my .vimrc file if there is any other binding to <kbd>Ctl</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>, but I found none.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<C-P>` and `<C-p>` are different: you are mapping something to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> but you are hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>.

What happens when you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>?

Comment: You are right, I missunderstood the answer in the other post, it seemed that the "kbd" tag indicated that the "p" displayed was in lower case, when it should be in upper case.

Comment: OK, I just fixed the other answer. I've changed the mapping from `<C-P>` to `<C-p>`. I think that you should do the same as `<C-p>` is slightly more convenient than `<C-P>` (less finger stretching).